# How to register with my "unregistered" profile

Tags: support, sign-up

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87053/how-to-use-fem-to-solve-a-pde) on math.stackexchange.com, without registration. Then I registered using the same email I've used for asking that question and expected the two profiles to be connected.

I searched for previous questions concerning the same issue, but unfortunately they seam to talk about old versions of the site.

Comment: Just flag the question for moderator attention and request that the mods merge that account with yours.  The system alone can't might not get this right and really needs human intervention.  If they can see it is clearly yours, they'll most likely do it.